# Performance overhead of TDE on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Has anyone used TDE on SQL Server 2008? What are the performance overheads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the largest overhead when using TDE is CPU resource requirements. If your server has sufficient processing power then you are most likely good to go.

For further reading take a look at the following resources.

[SQL Server Optimization And The Performance Impact Of Encryption](http://www.streetdirectory.com/travel_guide/125755/security/sql_server_optimization_and_the_performance_impact_of_encryption.html)

[Understanding Transparent Data Encryption(TDE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx)

[Transparent Data Encryption Considerations](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/transparent-data-encryption-considerations/)

I hope this helps and if you have further questions just let me know.